# BASH: the script quits without an error after an IF condition (possible bug?)

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
DOMAIN="mydomain.net"
if [ "${DOMAIN}" != "null" ]; then
SSL_CUSTOM=$(echo ${DOMAIN}| grep -c 'myapi.com')
fi
echo $SSL_CUSTOM
```

This should simply echo 0 in the output, BUT it seems to exit after the SSL_CUSTOM condition line without throwing an exit code.

Here's the debug output:

```
+ DOMAIN=mydomain.net
+ '[' mydomain.net '!=' null ']'
++ echo mydomain.net
++ grep -c myapi.com
+ SSL_CUSTOM=0
```

I could really use an advice what am I doing wrong here. I spent hours on trying to track down the issue in this simple code.

Thanks

Comment: _Works on my machine (tm)_ -- you're missing something from your question.

Comment: yes!
there's a set -e on the beginning. When I commented it out, it works. Hm.

Comment: `set -e` causes your script to abort as soon as there's a command that exits non-zero. `grep`, if no matches are found` exits non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comment with an answer:

```bash
SSL_CUSTOM=$(echo ${DOMAIN}| grep -c 'myapi.com' || true)
# ...............................................^^^^^^^
```

That lets `grep -c` do what it does, but if no matches are found, the exit status of the pipeline will be "success"

---

grep exit status demo:

```bash
$ seq 1 8 | grep -c 0
0
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons why "blindly" using `set -e` is not wise. Extra attention is needed so surprises like this don't happen.

Comment: Further reading: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish, so I will fill the gaps with guesses. You have an echo at the end, giving something like 0 or 1. You are also mentioning exit codes.
I'm guessing that you want

```
exit $SSL_CUSTOM
```

as your last line.